# Why can't I insert row into Entity Framework table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have used the option to generate EF code from the DB. When I try to insert, I get the error that "bundle_id" is required, even though what I'm inserting has a bundle_id.

Here is my code

```
[Table("[storage.tblCBMinCreditRequirement]")]
public partial class storage_tblCBMinCreditRequirement
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string bundle_id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string deal_detail_id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string version_code { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string applicant_id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string score { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string thin_no_hit { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string thin_no_hit_proxy { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string thin_file { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string thin_file_no_hit { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string limited_credit_flag { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string limited_credit_empl { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string limited_credit_sat_auto { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string qualified_trades { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string sat_auto_mortgage_trade { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string min_num_sat_auto_trade { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string total_bks { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string delinquent_mortgage { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string delinquent_auto { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string high_credit_amount { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string min_age_on_file { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string min_fico { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? CBCreditScoreFactors_Id { get; set; }
}

storage_tblCBMinCreditRequirement newt = InsertTable<storage_tblCBMinCreditRequirement>(new storage_tblCBMinCreditRequirement(), "/Loan/CoApplicant/CBCreditScoreFactors/CBMinCreditRequirement");

db.storage_tblCBMinCreditRequirement.Add(newt); 
db.SaveChanges();//throws exception
```

Here is my DB.
[image: DB Image]

Here is my entity
[image: Entity 1]
[image: Entity 2]

Here is my error
[image]

Thanks for any help, I'm stumped! :) And now, a poem for stack overflow, for being ridiculous in wanting more of a description.

Stack overflow, 
  you should know,
That code is the mode,
  to display my rage at the machine.

How else will I debug thee? What vain words do you want from me?
Must my idle words be of use? How does thou determine the value of my words and code? Is not code enough? Does forced poetry do you justice, O' Stack Overflow?

Comment: bundle_id is a PK and therefore by default an Identity property. use DatabaseGeneratedOption.None instead.

Comment: Just to add to @DevilSuichiro the reason that flag has to be there is how Entity Framework composes the insert statement for Primary Keys. The default is set to DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity. When this is set the column is actually excluded from the generated sql insert statement as it is expecting SQL to generate the value. An interesting thing to do is to spin up a SQL Profiler and analyze the differences between the two settings.

Comment: **dbo.storage.tblCBMinCreditRequirement**! Why not to create _storage_ schema and write **storage.tblCBMinCreditRequirement** instead?

Comment: *for being ridiculous in wanting more of a description* I think it's ridiculous to resist requests for more information preemptively. You don't show all relevant code, so this question can't be answered.

Comment: @GertArnold What am I missing?

Comment: What happens in `InsertTable`? Are there any associations to `storage_tblCBMinCreditRequirement`?

Comment: @GertArnold InsertTable simply builds the object from the XML file

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @DevilSuichiro's original comment you'll need to set the DatabaseGeneratedOption.None on the property bundle_id of your entity like below. The fully qualified name was provided so you don't have to hunt for the namespace :)

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[StringLength(255)]   
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] // Located here: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
public string bundle_id { get; set; }
```

**Why?**

By default DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity is set by default in Entity Framework on a primary key column. This indicates that the *Database* is responsible for generating the value. As a result, Entity Framework excludes the column from any generated SQL *Insert* statements as it is expecting SQL to generate the value.

To see this in action, either use

```
yourDbContext.Database.Log() = (query) => Debug.WriteLine(query);
```

before you execute SaveChanges or run a SQL Profiler to see the differences in the generated SQL.

**UPDATE**

For clarity, when you use the Database.Log() = (query) => Debug.WriteLine(query); the results are output to the Diagnostic Tools window of Visual Studio. This is launched by default when you start a debugging session *unless* you previously closed the window.

If it is not showing up for you while debugging it can be found here: Debug -> Windows -> Show Diagnostic Tools.

Below is a sample output so you know what you are looking for:

[image: Sample Diagnostic Tool Output]

Comment: Do you mean to use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] and also with that it's still not working :-/

Comment: My mistake. I updated the post with the necessary corrections.

Comment: Were you able to see what the generated SQL is? With these settings included are are seeing the bundle_id column in the insert statement?

Comment: Trying to use db.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s); but I can't see the output

Comment: Should be outputting to the Diagnostics window (not the output window) of visual studio. They will show up as "Events".

Comment: Were you able to see the output? Are you still receiving the same error as the original question?

Comment: Nobody seems to notice that bundle_id is a string property and, hence, will never be treated as a identity column by EF. This answer is off the mark.

Answer (score -1):

You can try hidden for `bundle_id` in your cshtml file.